# Why a bar of empty space appears below footer when I absolutely position an id container with a p element inside it?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to horizontally center a p element which resides inside a section with an id of 'copyright', inside a footer element. I've tried to give footer a position:relative and then add position:absolute as well as top:25px parameters to the id="copyright" to horizontally align it to the center of footer element. However, if I try this method or padding-top:25px, I always get a bar of empty space below the footer section. Additionally, the paragraph is not even centered. Can someone explain me why this is happening ? Thanks

Here's the code :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cwyfb

Comment: I was having alot of alike problems and i always solve it with placing text in alother div and with text-align: center and some another comands...

Comment: **"I don't understand is it me or is CSS a terribly confusing language when it comes to layout creation ? All I hear constantly about this language is 'hacks' cause otherwise this doesn't work, that doesn't work."** - Is this really necessary? Css isn't confusing you just don't understand it.

Comment: You were never frustrated when something was not going according to your plan ? Tell me then your magic solution to learn the CSS without pulling off all my hair ;)

Comment: Absolutely and I think everyone that's learns css or indeed any other language goes through the same frustrations - perhaps css is worse than a programming/scripting language because it doesn't throw any errors, but Stack Overflow is for questions. You should try to compose your questions as concisely as possible. The rant adds nothing to your question. There's no magic solution to learn anything but there is a wealth of excellent resources (books, video led training like code school and treehouse) to learn the basics. Learning the basics will help you avoid having to pull your hair out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit it and kick out the unnecessary sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line drops out of view because you padded it way too much.  And you have to use text-align to center your text.  You don't need to specify a width of 100% or a max-width; because you're  using absolute positioning, you can just set left and right to 0.

```
footer {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
    background:#333333;
}

#copyright {
    position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
    top: 5px;
}

#copyright p {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif, arial, verdana;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: white;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmDjs

NOTE: This uses no "hacks".  This is regular CSS.  The original code just wasn't implemented right.

Comment: But I thought that padding is pushing the element by default (like a magnet) from certain direction, so if the footer's height is 50px then adding a padding-top of 25px will push the paragraph exactly to the middle of the bar (y axis) :)

I don't know is it important but I'm actually trying to build a responsive website and I've been instructed in the tutorial to implement width:auto and max-width:900px in here. I'm following this tutorial : http://www.lingulo.com/tutorials/css/how-to-build-a-html5-website-from-scratch-part-2

Comment: Padding is exactly that: the distance that is padded between the edges of two elements.  A padding of 25px puts 25px of space between the two elements.  If your elements was 50px tall in a 100px container then 25px padding would center it vertically.

Comment: Also the `left:0` and `right:0` are perfectly fine for fluid layouts.  They just keep the edges of your section in line with the edges of your footer, wherever they may be.  The footer can still be as fluid as it likes.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to override the default margins using `*{margin:0}`. 
and apply `line-height:50px` for the footer to vertically center align the text.

You can then simply position the footer at bottom by adding `position:absolute; bottom:0;`

For center aligning the text in footer content apply remove `position:absolute` from `#copyright and`text-align:center`

You can also refer the demo in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354557/how-to-put-a-min-height-in-a-relative-class-css/24354647#24354647) for aligning footer to bottom regardlsee of the size on content

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cwyfb)

Comment: This only works if your layout is completely static.  It's not going to work for anything that isn't totally rigid.

Comment: @ndm13 my answer is just for the codepen shared in question. if the OP provides more info regarding the rest of html and css, i'll update the answer accordingly.. :)

Comment: Actually I was challenging myself to do a responsive website so the footer section needs to respond to browser's active area changes.

Comment: @Danny_Student refer to the demo in the question i mentioned above, which will respond to the change in contents...